# Google Geocoding API error message "Keyless access to google Maps platform is Deprecated..."

Tags: google-maps, desktop-application, livecode

In a standalone Desktop-application written in LiveCode (9.0.1, but I have the same issue in earlier versions of LiveCode), I am seemingly randomly receiving an error "Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is Deprecated.  Please use an API key with all your API calls..." when attempting to get Geocodeing results with Google-Maps.  I sometimes receive correct results with the same test address, and the same handler.

I am including a Google API, I have turned on billing with a valid payment card. I am still within the initial $300 trial credit, but I have enabled billing and have double checked that it is turned on.  I have tried the API as both the value stored in an Variable and directly in the URL text.  I have the API authorized for geocodeing, places, and static maps.  It works flawlessly with the static maps.  I have not tried with places yet.

```
put "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" & tAddress & \
     "&Key=" & APIKey into ltTestURL
put JSONToArray(url(ltTestURL)) into aGeocodeInfo
```

I currently have a repeat block that tries, with a .5 second wait, until the request succeeds.  It usually succeeds within a few seconds, but I would prefer to find the root of the problem.

Regards,

Comment: Perhaps use `&key=` (lower case `key`) in the URL

Comment: That seems to have done it.   From the two down votes i owe appologies for the question though.

Answer (score 2):

Geocodezip found it, the upper case K in "&key="

> Perhaps use &key= (lower case key) in the URL – geocodezip

Thank you for finding my typo.